# Android Studio AVD Manager button is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm very new to Android development and have never used Android Studio before. I set it up, got my app working on my phone and left it alone for a few weeks. Upon returning, I could not find the Android Studio executable on my computer, so I reinstalled it and restarted on the same project.

Not sure if this has to do with the AVD Manager button being grayed out. Things I have tried:

1. Making sure my SDK path is correct
2. Running Android Studio as administrator
3. Launching the AVD Manager executable from windows. I can create a virtual device but doesn't affect disabled AVD Manager button when restarting Android Studio.
4. Installing Intel X86 Atom System Image and Google APIs in SDK Manager, under API 24.Everything under API 25 is installed.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you can't figure it out, you could try a physical device or Genymotion. https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This generally happens when Android Studio is not able identify the android sdk installation in the machine. This could happen if Android Studio is launched in non-Administrator mode.

Just close and relaunch Android Studio in administrator mode. You will see a saying "android framework is identified" Click on the configure link on that notification. The AndroidStudio will start configuring the android sdk. After some time the buttons would be visible and enabled.

Comment: Ah, thanks a million. This worked. Should've listened to the pop-up notification!

Comment: @muhammad I have tried the solution you have mentioned above.But I did not get any pop up like "android framework is identified" and my AVD manager icon is still grayed.Can you please help me on this? Please note Android studio version 2.3 and SDK also updated and it is well identified under SDK manager as well.What would be the cause of this grayed out?

Comment: It disappears quickly on startup, so look out for it. Bottom right of screen

Comment: I had a very similar issue to this which I eventually found was that Android Studio was not recognising my project as an 'android framework' project. I had been using Webstorm previously to work on my react-native project, once I deleted the '.idea' directory in the root of my project and re-opened it in Android studio, I got the popup at the bottom right of the Android studio UI telling me that 'Android framework is identified'.

Answer (score 28):

If you tried running the Android Studio in administrator mode and it still do not work for you try the following way.

1. Delete the .idea folder in the project
2. Re open the project from going to File->Open Recent->
3. Then you will be asked to convert the project
4. Click convert

Comment: Especially true if you've opened the project previously on other JB IDE (e.g. Webstorm), which had generated the .idea folder.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I opened another React Native project and then went back to this one, and the AVD Manager icon was diabled and it wasn't giving me that "configure" option. I deleted the `.idea` folder as recommended here, opened another project from recent, then opened this project again from recent, and then it asked me to "configure" which is that magic button that enables the AVD Manager. Now its working as normal. Thanks x9001.

Comment: This project wasnt available in 'recent projects' probably because I was already in it, so thats why I opened a different one first.

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` folder worked for me without running on administrator mode. It asked me to install a few stuff and the AVD manager icon lit up! :)

Comment: Had same issue. Just make sure that your project is build and there is no errors. For me it was missing "build tools v26...." or something like that.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone seeing this problem following the [React Native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) make sure to click the "Configure" button in the Event Log next to the log text that reads "Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project"

This action seems to be what configures the project to be an Android project.

[image: screenshot of event log message]

Comment: We need to create a new project for this. And if any components are missing, install as suggested in the log view

Comment: Also helpful for those following the official Flutter tutorial:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 5):

I'v solved this issue by updating gradle.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in android studio or intellij program:

- goto tools > android > SDK manager
- click on Edit  (android SDK location)
- click next and next
- close dialog

its ok.

Answer (score 2):

**It is simple**

The only thing that worked for me was that I clicked in Androidstudio in the top right on **SDK Managar**.

And there under android sdk it was so that there was no path entered. and it was also so that NO Check box was checked below.
So I had to first click in the top right on Edit thereby was written to me the path pure.
After that I had to select a chack box below it no matter whiche and sometimes it must then just install something. When it has finished installing click OK. It may be that you then have to close and open android studio again.

Comment: This is the way. Android Studio can still create devices using Device Managed tab, but the options under tool is only enabled if the SDK path is present. This can be missing when you update Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

1. (You have perhaps just reinstalled `Android Studio`.)
2. Close the project. (`Android Studio` would have opened it for you.)
3. `Android Studio` will now not show you the usual list of projects. It will tell you instead that the SDK is not installed and lead you to installing it.

The `Android Device Manager` will be installed along.

If you do not want to pollute your user space with the SDK, make sure to select a neutral location (`/usr/local` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on a new machine running MacOS High Sierra.

After installing Android Studio and the most recent SDK/
SDK Tools, I was unable to create any AVD from Android Studio (button greyed out, no option under `Tools`) or run the AVD Manager any other way.

I tried the same things the OP had done, then noticed I was getting the following error: `Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2`

From the Event Log I followed a link to download the Build tools and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Flutter, Follow the steps:

- Open **Settings** in Android Studio (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)
- Search **Flutter**
- Check may path of Flutter SDK is not available.
- Set the path and press OK.

Done! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers here, but the only solution for me was to restart my machine and it fixed itself. It happened after upgrading AS (from 4.0.2 to 4.2.2)