# Android Studio 2.3 AVD Manager Greyed out?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just recently installed Android Studio (Version 2.3) so I could use the SDK / AVD GUI manager built in now that the standalone is deprecated. I'm on Windows 10 and this is a fresh install. My goal is to be able to setup a virtual device as well as setup my own android device to run a NativeScript app. After install the SDK button is available, but the AVD button is disabled (below).

[image]

I have the Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) SDK Platform installed and the Intel x86 Emulator Acc. installed (below). This is all default installs so far.

[image]

I've tried installing / reinstalling as admin as well as opening as admin per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290134/android-studio-avd-manager-button-is-disabled) to no avail.

The Android SDK home path, build target, and Java SDK are setup in the project structure by default correctly as well.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

As a side note the [android help page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html?hl=zh-tw) for creating AVD's lists a menu option (tools -> android ) which doesn't exist.

Comment: I also run into exact same problem.I tried all the possible things which you already have tried But nothing works
So i did workaround by Manually installing the from SDK Manager from platform-tools

Comment: Did you have, at least, one SDK Platform downloaded? If not, that's the reason of the grayed icon. I ask this because the tab screen you shared doesn't reveal that you have a 7.1.1 API SDK Platform.

Comment: Yeah Android studio comes with the 7.1.1 SDK platform installed (first tab). Really weird they don't just have everything working out of the box for a standard install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My issue was Android Studio does not understand where to load the nativescript android project even after adding android as a platform (If someone knows a way around this, feel free to post). In my particular case I'm testing the [angular-seed-advanced](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced). To at least get the command line working (AVD manager is still greyed out):

- Create a new blank android "test" project in android studio
- The AVD Manager becomes available
- Setup an virtual devices as necessary
- Reopen nativescript project
- use command `npm run start.android`
- prepare, build, run and livesync will work as expected now.

Hope this helps someone else get started.