# I installed packages of Android Studio as normall user. so how to open it as root?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, root

I downloaded Android Studio compressed file, then extract it to the /opt/ after that I run studio.sh as normal user and installed (downloaded) packages (such as Android emulator) through Android Studio need to download to run Android Studio.

Now, when I run Android Studio AVD manager is not working. So, I found this question answer on stackoverflow [Android Studio AVD Manager button is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290134/android-studio-avd-manager-button-is-disabled) , where it is written to open it as root to solve this problem.

So, when I open it as root, it prompt again package installation step. It is almost like 1GB. Where, when I am not using sudo it is opening normally (as I installed packages).

So, how to copy packages from normal user to sudo? or give any other solution to get access to those packages as sudo to run Android Studio normally.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem is moving `Android` folder from `/home/user` to `/root` folder.

Comment: you shouldn't give non-system app root privilege or running it from root. Instead you can give the privilege via group access privilege.

Comment: How to give group access privilege? @ישו אוהב אותך